# NPX command not able to install Playwright browsers (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, playwright, npx

I am having an issue with getting the following command to work to install Playwright browsers:

```
npx playwright install
```

I have already following installed on my computer (Win 10 64-bit):

- Node.js  version  18.16.0
- Npm      version  9.8.1

I have also previous to this managed to initiate a Playwright project through the following command:

```
npm init playwright@latest
```

So I have now a folder structure with package.json, package-lock.json, playwright.config.js and following folders: node_modules, tests and tests-example.

But it seems like no matter what I am doing I am not progressing because I always get this error message when I run the npx command:

[image]

I have tried with so many steps like clearing the cache, setting the registry in npm config to point to http instead of https and setting strict-ssl to false. I still dont get it to work. I am totally out of clue what else might be causing this.

Any advice would be highly valuable and appreciated.

Please let me know if you need additional details about anything, my npm configuration or anything else.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Is it possible you are behind a firewall or proxy? If yes, please refer to https://playwright.dev/docs/browsers#install-behind-a-firewall-or-a-proxy

Comment: @RobinThomas Is there any particular way for me to find out this?

Comment: It's important that the error be text, not an image, for [many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), including discoverability. Others that have the same error will have no easy way to find this thread, since images aren't searchable.